# How to get datetime of n weekdays before today

Tags: python

I want to get the datetime of N weekdays before today. Which function can help me to realize it? I try my best to search it but doesn't work.

Comment: can you include an example?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I got it.`pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(1)` works

Comment: If you mention pandas you can add the pandas tag with the question

Comment: OK, thank you for reminding.